# What framing is needed for swinging closet doors?

Tags: doors, closet

How do you frame an existing, finished opening for double swinging closet doors to be installed?

Comment: Double swinging, as in 2 doors, hinged on either side of the opening?

Comment: What material is currently in the opening?

Comment: Similar: [How can double swinging closet doors be installed?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/24614/how-can-double-swinging-closet-doors-be-installed?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

You usually start with the current opening (if finished)  and pick a standard door size, add in for gaps (3 gaps: Left hinge, right hinge and center).

Typical gap sizes would be 1/8 on either side and 3/16 in the middle

If the opening is currently drywall, the corner beads would be removed and a wooden jamb is installed left, top and bottom.  Casing molding is installed over the jamb to cover the gap between the jamb and the original opening.

Roller catches at the top center are nice, because there is not a usual single door strike plate

You have a choice of door handles (which will need wider stiles) or cabinet pulls,

Comment: The opening has a bi-fold door right now that sits in a track and we want to replace with double doors, it is too small for a regular size door. If suggestions of better options are available, I'm certainly open to them.

Comment: I'm confused by "it is too small for a regular door"...

Comment: It is a pantry and just looking at it, I don't think a full size door would fit, also we don't want one that large, would rather have 2 doors that swing out and take less space when they are open - into a small hallway.